Can we set the SP register to 0 in x86 assembly real mode?
I was following a tutorial on operating system development, and as a bit of a fanatic, I came across a line in the code that caught my attention:
bits 16

section _ENTRY CLASS=CODE

extern _cstart_

global entry

entry:
    cli
    mov ax, ds
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0
    mov bp, sp
    sti

    call _cstart_

    cli
    hlt

The stack pointer (SP) is initialized to 0. Won't there be a problem when we make a call (which is essentially a push, so SP would decrement to -1)?
The code runs fine, but I don't get why the stack pointer can be a negative number.

sp will wrap around to 0FFFFh if decremented from the zero value by one, and so on. I guess they want the stack to start at the very top of the data segment here.

A bit of an off topic question. Is this tutorial free? I might want to check it out too. How can I find it?

push first decrements the stack pointer and then stores value on top of the stack. Address of the first instruction after the call which is cli will be stored at 0xFFFE.

sp = 0001h could be a problem because pushing one 16-bit word (2 bytes sized) would decrement to sp = FFFFh and a word write at offset 0FFFFh in a Real/Virtual 86 Mode stack segment may fault on a 286+ or 386+. No such problem with sp = 0000h and pushing a word: The stack pointer will underflow to sp = FFFEh and store the pushed word at the very end of ss, at offset FFFEh (low byte) and FFFFh (high byte).

@Moses it's a playlist on x86 assembly but after some video he starts an OSdev project https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2EF13wm-hWCoj6tUBGUmrkJmH1972dBB&si=PRiQpCY2VkYOGjdW

Yes, setting sp to 0 works fine and is fairly common.
Remember that computers don't inherently see register values as "positive" or "negative"; they're just bits.  When sp = 0 and you execute a near call or a push, then sp is decremented by 2 (not 1 - remember that we are pushing 2-byte words), and the resulting value in sp is the address for the store.
Under the normal rules of 16-bit two's complement arithmetic, 0 - 2 = 0xfffe; i.e. it wraps around mod 2^16.  A borrow occurs, but it is ignored here.  (sub sp, 2 would set the carry flag CF to indicate the borrow, but the arithmetic done by stack manipulation instructions doesn't touch FLAGS.)
If you think of 0xfffe as a signed quantity, then yes, it is the number -2, but we think of addresses as unsigned.
So, the effect of mov sp, 0 is to locate the stack at the very top of the ss segment.
